# Equivalent of SAS proc mixed in R

Tags: r, sas, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to convert the following SAS code in R to get the same result that I get from SAS. Here is the SAS code:

```
    DATA plants; 
    INPUT  sample $  treatmt $ y ; 
    cards; 

    1   trt1    6.426264755 
    1   trt1    6.95419631 
    1   trt1    6.64385619 
    1   trt2    7.348728154 
    1   trt2    6.247927513 
    1   trt2    6.491853096 
    2   trt1    2.807354922 
    2   trt1    2.584962501 
    2   trt1    3.584962501 
    2   trt2    3.906890596 
    2   trt2    3 
    2   trt2    3.459431619 
    3   trt1    2 
    3   trt1    4.321928095 
    3   trt1    3.459431619 
    3   trt2    3.807354922 
    3   trt2    3 
    3   trt2    2.807354922 
    4   trt1    0 
    4   trt1    0 
    4   trt1    0 
    4   trt2    0 
    4   trt2    0 
    4   trt2    0 
    ; 
    RUN; 

    PROC MIXED ASYCOV NOBOUND  DATA=plants ALPHA=0.05 method=ML; 
    CLASS sample treatmt; 
    MODEL  y = treatmt ; 
    RANDOM int treatmt/ subject=sample ; 
    RUN;
```

I get the following covariance estimates from SAS:

> ```
> Intercept   sample  ==> 5.5795     
> Treatmt  sample ==> -0.08455      
> Residual         ==> 0.3181
> ```

I tried the following in R, but I get different results.

```
s=as.factor(sample) 
lmer(y~ 1+treatmt+(1|treatmt:s),REML=FALSE)
```

Comment: Have you read this yet? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SASmixed/vignettes/Usinglmer.pdf

Comment: I don't see any programming question here. Maybe [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SASmixed/vignettes/Usinglmer.pdf) can help you .

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with `contrast`?  From the readings I suggested and @agstudy, it appears that the main difference is in defining the `contrast`.  The authors' suggest for simplicity to define this `options(contrasts = c(factor = "contr.SAS", ordered = "contr.poly"))`  After apply this, I was able to get the signed coefficients where the treatment is now negative (-.1072)  and intercept is still positive (3.3391).

Comment: Thanks Amstell and agstudy. I will look into the link that you provided. @Amstell, your values are close. I will try and start from your code. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you'll be able to get the exact results from SAS to R, but I was able to get close by dealing with `contrast` as outlined here :

[lmer for SAS PROC MIXED Users](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SASmixed/vignettes/Usinglmer.pdf) : page 6

> When comparing estimates produced by SAS PROC MIXED and by lmer one
>   must be careful to consider the contrasts that are used to define the
>   effects of factors. In SAS a model with an intercept and a qualitative
>   factor is defined in terms of the intercept and the indicator
>   variables for all but the last level of the factor. The default
>   behaviour in S is to use the Helmert contrasts for the factor. On a
>   balanced factor these provide a set of orthogonal contrasts. In R the
>   default is the “treatment” contrasts which are almost the same as the
>   SAS parameterization except that they drop the indicator of the first
>   level, not the last level. When in doubt, check which contrasts are
>   being used with the contrasts function. To make comparisons easier,
>   you may find it worthwhile to declare
>
> `options(contrasts = c(factor = "contr.SAS", ordered = "contr.poly"))` at the beginning of your session.

dput :

```
df <- structure(list(sample = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    treatmt = c("trt1", "trt1", "trt1", "trt2", "trt2", "trt2", 
    "trt1", "trt1", "trt1", "trt2", "trt2", "trt2", "trt1", "trt1", 
    "trt1", "trt2", "trt2", "trt2", "trt1", "trt1", "trt1", "trt2", 
    "trt2", "trt2"), y = c(6.426264755, 6.95419631, 6.64385619, 
    7.348728154, 6.247927513, 6.491853096, 2.807354922, 2.584962501, 
    3.584962501, 3.906890596, 3, 3.459431619, 2, 4.321928095, 
    3.459431619, 3.807354922, 3, 2.807354922, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), .Names = c("sample", "treatmt", "y"))
```

Current Code :

```
options(contrasts = c(factor = "contr.SAS", ordered = "contr.poly"))
df$sample=as.factor(df$sample) 
lmer(y~ 1+treatmt+(1|treatmt:sample),REML=FALSE, data = df)
```

Current Output :

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: y ~ 1 + treatmt + (1 | treatmt:sample)
   Data: df
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 80.3564  85.0686 -36.1782  72.3564       20 
Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Std.Dev.
 treatmt:sample (Intercept) 2.344   
 Residual                   0.564   
Number of obs: 24, groups:  treatmt:sample, 8
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  treatmttrt1  
     3.3391      -0.1072
```

Comment: Hi Amstell, thanks a lot for taking time to help me. I am interested on  the variance components of the random effects and not on the coefficients of the fixed effects. I get the following covariance estimates from SAS:

Intercept sample ==> 5.5795
treatmt sample ==> -0.08455
Residual ==> 0.3181

Answer (score 0):

You are using the SAS option `NOBOUND` which allows negative estimates of the variances, and you get a negative estimate. This is not possible with `lmer`, which constraints the variances to be positive.

We can try to get the SAS results manually. Firstly, note that the equivalent `lmer` syntax is:

```
lmer(y ~ 1 + treatment + (1+treatment|sample), REML=FALSE, data = dat)
```

Let's maximize the log-likelihood, allowing negative variances:

```
dattxt <- "1 trt1  6.426264755 
1 trt1  6.95419631 
1 trt1  6.64385619 
1 trt2  7.348728154 
1 trt2  6.247927513 
1 trt2  6.491853096 
2 trt1  2.807354922 
2 trt1  2.584962501 
2 trt1  3.584962501 
2 trt2  3.906890596 
2 trt2  3 
2 trt2  3.459431619 
3 trt1  2 
3 trt1  4.321928095 
3 trt1  3.459431619 
3 trt2  3.807354922 
3 trt2  3 
3 trt2  2.807354922 
4 trt1  0 
4 trt1  0 
4 trt1  0 
4 trt2  0 
4 trt2  0 
4 trt2  0 
"

dat <- read.table(text = dattxt)
names(dat) <- c("sample", "treatment", "y")
dat$sample <- as.factor(dat$sample)

opts <- options(contrasts = c(factor = "contr.SAS", ordered = "contr.poly"))

library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(y ~ 1 + treatment + (1+treatment|sample), REML=FALSE, data = dat) 

# marginal variance matrix in function of variance components
Vfun <- function(fit, vcs){
  Z <- getME(fit, "Z")
  n <- getME(fit, "n")
  l_i <- getME(fit, "l_i")
  sigma2_a <- vcs[1]
  sigma2_b <- vcs[2]
  sigma_ab <- vcs[3]
  sigma2 <- vcs[4]
  G <- matrix(c(sigma2_a, sigma_ab, sigma_ab, sigma2_b), nrow = 2)
  R <- Diagonal(n, sigma2)
  Z %*% bdiag(rep(list(G),l_i)) %*% t(Z) + R
}


# minus log-likelihood
library(mvtnorm)
logLHD <- function(params, fit){
  X <- getME(fit, "X")
  beta <- params[1:ncol(X)]
  y <- getME(fit, "y")
  vcs <- tail(params, length(params)-ncol(X))
  V <- as.matrix(Vfun(fit, vcs))
  if(any(eigen(V)$values <= 0)){
    return(runif(1, 1e7, 1e8)) # return a high-value if V is not positive
  }
  -dmvnorm(y, c(X%*%beta), sigma = V, log = TRUE)  
}

# optimization of log-likelihood
library(dfoptim)
start <- 
  c(fixef(fit), vc$sample[1,1], vc$sample[2,2], vc$sample[1,2], sigma(fit)^2)
names(start)[3:6] <- 
  c("sample.Intercept", "sample.trt1", "covariance", "sigma2")
opt <- hjkb(start, logLHD, lower=c(-Inf,-Inf,-Inf,-Inf,-Inf,0), fit=fit)

### results 
opt$par
# (Intercept) treatmenttrt1 sample.Intercept  sample.trt1 covariance     sigma2 
# 3.33912840    -0.10721533       5.50671885  -0.16909628 0.07275635 0.31812378
```

The residual variance is the same as the one obtained with SAS. To get the other SAS results, one has to do some gymnastic with our results, I don't understand why, but we get them in this way:

```
### SAS results
opt$par[["sample.Intercept"]] + opt$par[["covariance"]]
# 5.579475
opt$par[["sample.trt1"]] / 2
# -0.08454814
```

Note that the log-likelihood is indeed better maximized with the negative variance:

```
### remark: lmer achieves a lower log-likelihood
logLik(fit)
# 'log Lik.' -27.88947 (df=6)
-opt$value
# -26.43355
```

I would appreciate if someone could explain the required gymnastic...

---

## EDIT

Sorry, this is not the good model. The model is:

```
lmer(y ~ 1 + treatment + (1|sample/treatment), REML=FALSE, data = dat)
```

Here are the SAS results:

```
opts <- options(contrasts = c(factor = "contr.SAS", ordered = "contr.poly"))
library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(y ~ 1+treatment+(1|sample/treatment), REML=FALSE, data = dat) 
vc <- VarCorr(fit)

Vfun <- function(fit, vcs){
  Z <- getME(fit, "Z")
  n <- getME(fit, "n")
  l_i <- getME(fit, "l_i")
  G <- Diagonal(sum(l_i), rep(vcs[1:2], l_i))
  R <- Diagonal(n, vcs[3])
  Z %*% G %*% t(Z) + R
}

library(mvtnorm)
logLHD <- function(params, fit){
  X <- getME(fit, "X")
  beta <- params[1:ncol(X)]
  y <- getME(fit, "y")
  vcs <- tail(params, length(params)-ncol(X))
  V <- as.matrix(Vfun(fit, vcs))
  if(any(eigen(V)$values <= 0)) return(runif(1, 1e7, 1e8))
  -dmvnorm(y, c(X%*%beta), sigma = V, log = TRUE)  
}

library(dfoptim)
start <- c(fixef(fit), vc[[1]], vc[[2]], sigma(fit)^2)
opt <- hjkb(start, logLHD, lower=c(-Inf,-Inf,-Inf,-Inf,0), fit=fit)
opt$par[3:5]
# -0.08454877    5.57947601    0.31812697
```